# grouping in pandas and bar plotting with non numeric xlabels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, plot

I am struggling with some basic stuff and any help from you is very appreciated.
I have grouped some data and got the following result:

```
  LDI Bucket  Gross Loan Amount
0       0-3m                637
1       3-6m                363
2       6-9m                 90
3      9m-1y                147
```

Now I would like to plot this in a bar plot. So far I have used:

```
LDICount=data[data['LDI Bucket'].notnull()].groupby('LDI Bucket', as_index=False).agg({"Gross Loan Amount": "count"})

ax=LDICount.plot(kind='bar',title="LDI Duration", figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=1)
```

Question (1):

How can I extract a column from this grouping without having the indices in the output. For example doing LDICount['LDI Bucket'] gives me

```
0     0-3m
1     3-6m
2     6-9m
3    9m-1y
```

I dont want to have the index on the left

Question (2): how can I do a bar plot with x axis having `['0-3m',....,'9m-1y']` and y axis having 'Gross Loan Amount'

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the index of your data frame with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
LDICount = LDICount.set_index('LDI Bucket')
```

and then plot your data.

Comment: You might need to add a `.reset_index()` at then end of the groupby